# Unable to set nickname/change name of Google account

Tags: google-account

I am trying to change the name in my google account at https://aboutme.google.com/. I get the following error.

Trouble updating your information. Please try again later.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? A different network?

Comment: Same error in Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1 and Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit). Yes, tried different networks too.

Comment: It looks that there isn't anything that we can do for you other than suggesting to report this through Google Feedback / https://support.google.com/accounts/community